# Event notification Application error

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I get this error whenever i log on to my windows server 2008 "controller ID:0 Background initialization detected uncorrectable multiple medium errors".I really appreciate your contribution

Answer (score 1):

So, run the diags or other management tool for the controller in question. If you don't have them, download and install them.

Can't tell you much more without knowing what make and model of the controller (and server).

Page 33 : http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/systems/support/system_x_pdf/00d2404.pdf

> If the events are targeted to the same hard disk
>   drive, replace the drive. If the events point to
>   two or more drives, investigate other events to
>   determine the cause of this event. A
>   procedural, environmental, or physical problem
>   within the subsystem might have caused this
>   event. This might be a symptom of another
>   problem.
>
> 1. Evaluate previous events to determine
>      trending problems with physical devices.
> 2. If trending problems span multiple devices,
>      check and reseat cable and device
>      connections.
> 3. If trending problems are isolated to one
>      device, replace that device.
> 4. Manually begin a consistency check and
>      allow that process to be completed.
> 5. Evaluate the actions and conditions that
>      exhibited the problem, or observe for
>      normal behavior.

Comment: the controller model is "IBM ServeRAID-MR10i SCSI Disk Device" and the server model is "IBM X3650 M2,OS Windows 2K8 R1.Appreciates

Comment: Edited my answer based on the product documentation.

Comment: I really appreciate.I will try out the suggestions